Some UI are missing after I publish
when I tried to publish my game all of the components in the canvas went missing:
in the editor it works fine, no errors But when it shows on the webpage it miss all the UIs:
I'm wondering how to fix it.
I have tried(but all didn't work):

clean build it

delete the panel behind it



Looks like the way your UI has scaled with the screen.

Change the position of the panels to the middle of the screen and get the output. Do you see the panels?

Try to move all of your UI elements to position 0,0,0 like Hamed said. If you can see the UI elements it means you set the UI Anchors wrong. You can search for it.
